# calling function in codeigniter controller using ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a `codeigniter` website, where I have done an add to cart function, on button click the product is added to cart after page reloads which is working fine, I did the following code in controller:

```html
public function buy($id)
         {
           $color= $this->input->post('color');
           $size=$this->input->post('size');
             $product = $this->product->find($id);
             $item = array(
                 'id' => $product->id,
                 'name' => $product->pname,
                 'quantity' => 1
             );
             if(!$this->session->has_userdata('cart')) {
                 $cart = array($item);
                 $this->session->set_userdata('cart', serialize($cart));
             } else {
                 $index = $this->exists($id);
                 $cart = array_values(unserialize($this->session->userdata('cart')));
                 if($index == -1) {
                     array_push($cart, $item);
                     $this->session->set_userdata('cart', serialize($cart));
                 } else {
                     // $cart[$index]['quantity']++;
                     // $this->session->set_userdata('cart', serialize($cart));
                     $this->session->set_flashdata("Error","Product Already In Cart !");

                     redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                 }
             }
             $this->session->set_flashdata("Success","Product Added To Cart Successfully !");

             redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);


         }
```

Now I am trying to call this function using `ajax` so that the product is added to cart without page reload. I did the following code:

```js
$("#change").submit(function() {
  alert("Change");
  var id = $('#prod').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/homecontroller/buy/" + id,
    data: {
      'id': id
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#resultdiv').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="change">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $product->id; ?>" id="prod">
  <input type="submit" value="switch">
</form>
<div class="resultdiv">
  <?php echo $data; ?>
</div>
```

However it's not adding to cart, it simply reloads the page. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the form is still submitting, you can use preventDefault();

```
$("#change").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("Change");
  var id = $('#prod').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/homecontroller/buy/" + id,
    data: {
      'id': id
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#resultdiv').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: but still its not adding to cart

Comment: You need to pinpoint the issue; 1) check if the code works with regular forms without ajax, if it is working then 2) check console for other js/ajax related issues